# CSS BUTTON CENTERAL FIX

Tags: css

How can I put one button in the center of a web page?
(just with CSS codes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `position: fixed` and then

```
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
```

It will move the left top corner of button to the center of screen.

Use `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` to move the button to left by 50% of it's width, and up by 50% of it's height;

Answer (score 0):

@erfan_bp99 this can be done with simple CSS.

```css
button {
position: fixed;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
 /*Some extra styleing goes under this comment*/
padding: 15px;
cursor: pointer;
}
```

CodePen https://codepen.io/Mastercodetech/pen/BaWoBrq

You can just use

```
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
```